# Object reference not set to instance of object, despite creating a new object

Tags: c#, object, reference

I'm currently working on a basic drawing program. One of the requirements is to be able to save the list of drawn objects and load it back in. So far, I have written a save function that exports all items of the list to an XML format, and I'm currently working on the loading-part.

Whenever the program encounters a "< RechthoekTool >" (Dutch for RectangleTool), it executes the following code:

```
//Create new tool.
RechthoekTool tool = new RechthoekTool();

//Turn <Startpoint> and <Endpoint> into actual points
var sp = Regex.Replace(xn["Startpunt"].InnerText, @"[\{\}a-zA-Z=]", "").Split(',');
tool.startpunt = new Point(int.Parse(sp[0]), int.Parse(sp[1]));
var ep = Regex.Replace(xn["Eindpunt"].InnerText, @"[\{\}a-zA-Z=]", "").Split(',');
tool.eindpunt = new Point(int.Parse(ep[0]), int.Parse(ep[1]));

//Set colour and width of brush
string kleur = xn["Dikte"].InnerText;
kleur.Replace(@"Color [", "");
kleur.Replace(@"]", "");
Color c = Color.FromName(kleur);
tool.kwastkleur = c;
tool.kwast = new SolidBrush(c);
tool.dikte = int.Parse(xn["Dikte"].InnerText);

//Add to list
s.listItems.Add(tool);
```

Whenever I run the program, I get the 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' error("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") at

> s.listItems.Add(tool);

I do, however, instantiate the tool right at the beginning, don't I? What could be causing this error? Some Googling told me it might be because I forgot to assign a property, but as far as I can tell I've got them all covered...

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As David Arno said in his answer, check that `s` is not null and that `s.listItems` is not null.

Answer (score 9):

The error is due to `s` or `s.listItems` not being instantiated.

Without seeing more code, it's difficult to know which is null, but at a guess you are creating a new object for `s`, which contains a property/field `listItems`, but you aren't assigning a list to `listItems`.

Comment: Thanks; listItems was instantiated in a different class, but I didn't link it properly. It's working now.

Comment: @Biggar - If David solved your problem, please accept his answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't instantiating `listItems` or `s`. Not enough information is given to tell you how to instantiate `s` but you can do the other one like this:

```
s.listItems = new List<RechthoekTool>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't [instantiate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460654.aspx#InstantiatingClasses) something using the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/51y09td4.aspx) keyword; it simply won't work.

Using your code, try this:

```
//Create new tool.
RechthoekTool tool = new RechthoekTool();

//Turn <Startpoint> and <Endpoint> into actual points
var sp = Regex.Replace(xn["Startpunt"].InnerText, @"[\{\}a-zA-Z=]", "").Split(',');
tool.startpunt = new Point(int.Parse(sp[0]), int.Parse(sp[1]));
var ep = Regex.Replace(xn["Eindpunt"].InnerText, @"[\{\}a-zA-Z=]", "").Split(',');
tool.eindpunt = new Point(int.Parse(ep[0]), int.Parse(ep[1]));

//Set colour and width of brush
string kleur = xn["Dikte"].InnerText;
kleur.Replace(@"Color [", "");
kleur.Replace(@"]", "");
Color c = Color.FromName(kleur);
tool.kwastkleur = c;
tool.kwast = new SolidBrush(c);
tool.dikte = int.Parse(xn["Dikte"].InnerText);

List<RechthoekTool> s = new List<RechthoekTool>();  // You can now use your list.
//Add to list
s.listItems.Add(tool);
```